# Inject token from auth0 to React-admin Hasura data provider

Tags: apollo-client, auth0, react-admin, hasura

This [example](https://github.com/spintech-software/react-admin-auth0-example/blob/master/src/components/LoginForm.js) demonstrates how to use Auth0 with `react-admin`. It is working as expected.
We are trying to adjust it so it will use the [hasura data provider](https://github.com/hasura/ra-data-hasura). We've created a new file `dataProvider.js` that will construct the data-provider:

```js
import buildHasuraProvider from "ra-data-hasura";
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

export const initDataProvider = async (token) => {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_URI,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });

  const dataProvider = await buildHasuraProvider({ client });
  return dataProvider;
};
```

However, we are missing the JWT token which is created as part of the Auth0 authentication process. We do not know how to get the token in order to initialize the data provider with it. Does react-admin know how to do it on its own? if not, how do we access the JWT token to do it ourselves manually?

This is the `authProvider` source-code:

```js
import authConfig from "./authConfig";
import {Auth0Client} from '@auth0/auth0-spa-js';

const auth0 = new Auth0Client({
    domain: authConfig.domain,
    client_id: authConfig.clientID,
    redirect_uri: authConfig.redirectURI,
    cacheLocation: 'localstorage',
    useRefreshTokens: true
});

export default {
    // called when the user attempts to log in
    login: (url) => {
        if (typeof url === 'undefined') {
            return auth0.loginWithRedirect()
        }
        return auth0.handleRedirectCallback(url.location);
    },
    // called when the user clicks on the logout button
    logout: () => {
        return auth0.isAuthenticated().then(function (isAuthenticated) {
            if (isAuthenticated) { // need to check for this as react-admin calls logout in case checkAuth failed
                return auth0.logout({
                    redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
                    federated: true // have to be enabled to invalidate refresh token
                });
            }
            return Promise.resolve()
        })
    },
    // called when the API returns an error
    checkError: ({status}) => {
        if (status === 401 || status === 403) {
            return Promise.reject();
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
    },
    // called when the user navigates to a new location, to check for authentication
    checkAuth: () => {
        return auth0.isAuthenticated().then(function (isAuthenticated) {
            if (isAuthenticated) {
                return Promise.resolve();
            }
            return auth0.getTokenSilently()
        })
    },
    // called when the user navigates to a new location, to check for permissions / roles
    getPermissions: () => {
        return Promise.resolve()
    },
};
```

It is unclear to us if there is a point where we can extract the token from.

Answer (score 0):

[getTokenSilently](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-spa-js/classes/auth0client.html#gettokensilently) should give you back the token.

You'll have to structure your React app such that you have access to the result of this method before you construct your data provider.

Comment: I understand your comment "You'll have to structure your React app...". However this means we cannot use react-admin's AuthProvider, am I correct?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure as I haven't worked with react-admin before but but I'd be surprised if this were the case. You just need to make sure that you've retrieved the token before you render the Component that ultimately hooks up the React Admin data provider